# How to write current date into Cell of UITableView through NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

**I want the user to save the current date (like dd.mm.yyyy) to the `NSUserDefaults` by clicking a button and load it back in another `ViewController` to display it as a cell in `UITableView`. But it won't work. I don't know how to get the date right but this is what I tried:**

```
@IBAction func saveButtonTapped (sender:AnyObject){

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if var timeList = userDefaults.objectForKey("timeList") as? [NSDate]
    {
        timeList.append(NSDate())
        userDefaults.setObject(timeList, forKey: "timeList")
    }
    else
    {
        userDefaults.setObject([NSDate()], forKey: "timeList")
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

...

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var time:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timecopy = NSMutableArray(array: time)

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var timeListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("timeList") as? NSMutableArray

    if ((timeListFromUserDefaults) != nil){
        time = timeListFromUserDefaults!
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let timeListKey = "TimeList" // Key in user defaults

    var timeList: [NSDate] = [NSDate]() {
        didSet {
            userDefaults.setObject(self.timeList, forKey: timeListKey)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    //MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.timeList.append(NSDate())
    }


    //MARK: TableView DataSource
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.timeList.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "TimeListCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(timeList[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

    //MARK: View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Get NSArray from userDefaults
        let timeListFromUserDefaults = userDefaults.objectForKey(timeListKey) as? NSArray
        // Check if it is an array of NSDate, else set timeList to empty array
        self.timeList = (timeListFromUserDefaults as? [NSDate]) ?? [NSDate]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note I do not explicitly `synchronize` since it will automatically happen when your app goes in background or when the os thinks it is ok to do so. This is how you should do. If your app crashes, user defaults will not be saved ... and probably you want this, since the crash could be due to the data in your defaults. If those get saved than the app will continue to crash until the user delete it from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you put in `NSUserDefaults` is *saved* as immutable. Thus you will get back an `NSArray` not an `NSMutableArray`. This may cause your conditional casting to fail and return `nil`.

By the way, consider that `NSUserDefaults` is not intended to be some sort of DataBase for your app, but just a small `PropertyList` of preferenses and stuff like that.

If you are going to have lot of dates to save, delete etc., you should probably consider `CoreData` or other solutions.

Comment: 1. Doesn't "var timecopy = NSMutableArray(array: time)" make a mutable copy of the loaded array?

2. I'm aware of that but this is my first app so I try to keep it simple. What negative effects will the use of NSUserDefaults compared to CoreData have for the User?

Comment: @santa1 I think that `userDefaults.objectForKey("timeList") as? NSMutableArray` returns `nil` since it gets an `NSArray` from `NSUserDefaults`. I don't get the need of `var timecopy = NSMutableArray(array: time)`: it just creates a copy of `time` that never gets used.

Comment: @santa1 `NSUserDefaults` are serialised property lists, think of it as an XLM file. Searching, sorting, deleting and typical db operations will become quite inefficient as data grows. Since you use the shared instance `standardUserDefaults`, you could run into trouble when changing the model of your data in a future time.

Comment: Thanks so far. I've removed the copy. I get your point with using Core Data instead but atm I wanna keep it simple and make my NSUserDefaults work. So if you have another idea what could be wrong with my code please tell me.